# Clarification of the Jacobian

Tags: multivariable-calculus, recreational-mathematics, analytic-geometry

Well, that was cool if not tedious but I understand the Jacobian and its application to changing coordinate systems. $${J_{POLAR}= \rho}$$ $$    
{J_{cyl}= \rho}$$
and $${J_{sphere}=\rho^2\sin\phi}$$ Let me see if I have this right any time I find the area of a polar conic I take evaluate the integral like so $${\int_0^R\int_c^d \rho d\rho d\theta}$$ and similarly for volume in cylindrical and spherical respectively $${\int_0^R\int_o^\theta\int_0^z \rho \theta d\rho d\theta dz}$$ $${\int_0^R\int_0^\theta\int_0^\phi \rho^2\sin\phi d\rho d\theta d\phi}$$

Say for a conic in polar $$ {\rho = (ed/(1-e\sin\theta)}$$

Ok I just hit my next road block but let me take a shot in the dark the area under the conic would be??

I am lost here, but I think I get $${\int_0^R\int_0^\theta \rho[ (ed)/(1-e\sin\theta)]d\rho d\theta}$$

Uh.. that just does not look right..what am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you have $\;d\rho\;$ twice in the first double integral? And why doesn't "that" look right? In fact it does, assuming the integrals' limits are correct, of course....and they seem to be not.

Comment: So then my understanding is correct? Whenever I take the integral of equations in  Polar, cylindrical, or spherical form I have to multiply the function I am integrating by the jacobian?

As for the limits they run from zero to some arbitrary value of R, ${\theta}$, and ${\phi}$

Comment: Yes, that's right: you have to write down the function according to the chosen coordinates and *then* also multiply by the corresponding Jacobian (but only in case you changed coordinates!)

Comment: Which part of the question merits the "recreational" tag?

Comment: So then the volume under a conic-oid expressed in cylindrical coordinates will be...? 
$${\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \int _0^Z ρ[(ed)/(1−esinθ)]d\rho d\theta dz}$$ 
 and in spherical coordinates 
$${\int_0^R \int_0^{2\pi} \int _0^\pi ρ^2 \sin\phi[(ed)/(1−esinθ)]d\rho d\theta d\phi}$$ ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Some folks just do math for fun... at least I think its recreational.....But ok you have a point.